# Logical Partition not showing in Win7 after recovery

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning, logical-drive

I performed a recovery on my Toshiba Laptop P755. I chose recovery without changing partitions and all went well except that my 2nd partition (Data partition - Logical) is not showing in windows 7.

I tried assigning a letter to the partition in Disk Management, but it shows the error "The operation failed to complete because the disk management console is not up-to-date...". the partition is Logical, but in Disk management it's blue not green.

[image: Disk Management Error]

I tried a number of tools on Hiren's boot, some of them shows the partition as an unallocated space and others shows the partition normally.

The partition has 300 GB data and I can access it via Win XP by USB, but I cant's access it in win 7. 
it's all the same partitions as before recovery.
I tried Easy Recovery Essentials, it shows my whole HDD as an unallocated space.
I tried EaseUS on win 7, it shows all partitions including the missing one, but when I try to assign a letter it shows the error "Mounting volume failed!".

I tried Diskpart and it didn't show the missing partition.

I have all my data copied on a backup Drive, I just want to know if there is anything possible left to do before formatting the partition and copying the data back again.

Comment: I tried several partition softwares and no luck. I deleted the partition and im copying the data back.